# Put and Get Data from aws elasticache with java

Tags: java, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have read aws doc to find a way to put and get data into elasticache redis with java api but I cannot find one. Please suggest me with docs where I can get detail about this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://redis.io/clients#java.

The currently active Java Redis client projects are Jedipus, Jedis, Lettuce, and Redisson. [Lettuce](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core) and [Redisson](https://github.com/redisson/redisson) have more sophisticated support for AWS ElastiCache Redis than Jedipus and Jedis.